# jBPM 6.1 Human Task REST Start/Complete

Tags: java, rest, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm trying to make a REST POST call to Start a Human Task with this:

```
http://Administrator:superman@bpm.server.com/jbpm-console/rest/task/1/start
```

The *taskId* 1 is actually *Reserved* by the user *john.doe*, and when I execute the call the server responds with a status: **406 - Conflict**

I read in the documentation that the *Administrator* user is allowed to perform all actions for the tasks.

Do I have to pass another parameter indicating which *userId* is performing the action, besides the one who is executing the REST call? Do anyone knows how the parameter is called? Tried all the obvious names and still throws an error. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding the server response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <exception>
    <status>PERMISSIONS_CONFLICT</status>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/1/start</url>
    <message>PermissionDeniedException thrown with message 'User '[UserImpl:'bc-admin']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Start' on task id 1'</message>
    <stackTrace>org.kie.workbench.common.services.rest.RestOperationException: User '[UserImpl:'bc-admin']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Start' on task id 1
    ...
```

**EDIT 2:**

The Tasks properties are:

```
"people-assignments":{
  "potential-owner":[
    {"id":"HR","type":"GROUP"},
    {"id":"user@company.com","type":"USER"}],
  "business-administrator":[
    {"id":"Administrator","type":"USER"},
    {"id":"Administrators","type":"GROUP"}],
  "excluded-owners":[],
  "task-stakeholders":[],
  "recipients":[]}
  ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally and after a long long cry, I had to fork the REST API and add the functionality to it because it's missing.

Comment: Have you already found a way to do it? (without modifying the API source code)?

Comment: @DavidValdivieso nope, as far as I know, this behavior is still there. I read somewhere something about preventing impersonation but the Java API allows to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar error that I was running into while starting out with the remoting API, but I'm am not entirely sure since the error message looks like it might be cut off. If your error message ends with "due to a no 'current status' match" you are using the wrong command. In your comments it says that there are no actors defined, but there are groups defined. It is possible you might be forgetting to Claim the task before you call the Start command.

Can you check the status of task before you execute the command. I found that

```
Status         Expected Action
-------------------------------
Ready      --> Claim
Reserved   --> Start
InProgress --> Complete
```

Comment: Your point is right and is good clarification, however this is not the case since the task was already claimed and what the Administrator is intended to do is to Start the task in behalf of the user who claimed the task.

Comment: It seems like the REST Api lacks a param to execute the Start/Complete task by the Business Administrator in behalf of other user. I saw the docs for Java and the function receives an extra parameter with the userId.

Answer (score -1):

In The docs says the the business administrator of the task can do any action, but not the admin of the system.

Comment: It doesn't work with Administrator nor Business Administrator account. The docs are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMTaskService.html#jBPMTaskPermissions). No matter what, the API always responds with a **406 - Conflict**.

Comment: Can you check that the task has that property set? How are you setting the business administrator in the task? Because I still think that we are still talking about different administrator concepts.

Comment: The task has the "Actors" property as blank, and "Group" property as "admin, user". Where do you set the Business Administrator in a Human Task?

Comment: ok so that's the problem then, you need to set the business administrator for the task. Take a look at this example process, you can open it with the KIE Workbench -> Process Designer: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-playground/blob/master/human-resources/src/main/resources/hiring.bpmn2#L114
As far as I remember that process is setting the process initiator as business administrator for the task that are created inside that process instance. Having that set will enable you to execute administrator only operations on the tasks.

Comment: I verified the response returned from the task query and it returns this:
`"business-administrator":[{"id":"Administrator","type":"USER"},{"id":"Administrators","type":"GROUP"}],"excluded-owners":[],"task-stakeholders":[],"recipients":[]}`
So... nope, the Business Administrator looks ok to me. Still no luck with this one.

Comment: How did you setup the business administrator in the task? Can you share your business process? Or a simple process with one just task with the business administrator set.

Comment: Is a single human task process with the business administrator set in.

Comment: Can you share it so I can try to reproduce the issue? I recommend to create a Jira issue and attach the reproducer, because there must be something wrong in there. The process that I've provided 5 comments above is working in master.

Comment: Yes, here is [the process](https://github.com/BeatCoding/bpmsources/blob/master/SimpleTask/DocumentAuthorization/org.jbpm.Document%20Authorization.v1.0.bpmn2). Thanks in advance.